# iOS 8 AVFoundation - how to enable video stabilization on capable devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

Was excited to hear about the video stabilization on some of the new iPhones for a video app I'm doing, but how do you actually enable it for a recording session on a capable device? 
Looking at the API documentation, there is only a way to check if it is supported, the ways to switch it on/off are deprecated in iOS 8. Is it automatic or something?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009522-CH1-SW38

Answer (score 12):

You need to set the video AVCaptureConnection's preferredVideoStabilizationMode property, its default value is AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff so it won't be set automatically.

```
self.videoConnection = [self.videoOut connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (self.videoConnection.supportsVideoStabilization) {
        self.videoConnection.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto;
}
```

To get the connection's current AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode read its activeVideoStabilizationMode property.

From Apple's documentation:

> @property preferredVideoStabilizationMode
>
> This property is only applicable to AVCaptureConnection instances involving video.
>       On devices where the video stabilization feature is supported, only a subset of available source
>       formats may be available for stabilization.  By setting the preferredVideoStabilizationMode
>       property to a value other than AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff, video flowing through the receiver is stabilized
>       when the mode is available.  Enabling video stabilization introduces additional latency into the video capture pipeline and
>       may consume more system memory depending on the stabilization mode and format.  If the preferred stabilization mode isn't available,
>       the activeVideoStabilizationMode will be set to AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff.  Clients may key-value observe the
>       activeVideoStabilizationMode property to know which stabilization mode is in use or when it is off.  The default value
>       is AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff.  When setting this property to AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto, an appropriate
>       stabilization mode will be chosen based on the format and frame rate.  For apps linked before iOS 6.0, the default value
>       is AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeStandard for a video connection attached to an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput instance.
>       For apps linked on or after iOS 6.0, the default value is always AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff.  Setting a video stabilization
>       mode using this property may change the value of enablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable.

Answer (score 2):

While this question asks about video stabilization for iOS8; I just wanted to add some code in case people are trying to support versions earlier than iOS8 as well in their camera code.

```
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [self.captureVideoDataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ([videoConnection isVideoStabilizationSupported]) {
        if ([videoConnection respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredVideoStabilizationMode:)]) { // for iOS8+
            [videoConnection setPreferredVideoStabilizationMode:AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto];
        } else { // otherwise default to pre iOS8 way of doing it
            [videoConnection setEnablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable:YES];
        }
    }
```

Note that the compiler will introduce a deprecation warning on the pre iOS8 method call. If you are also OCD about warnings you can suppress it by surrounding the call to the depreciated method with #pragma like so:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
[videoConnection setEnablesVideoStabilizationWhenAvailable:YES];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

If people are interested, a little more information from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2409/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015038-CH1-CINEMATIC_VIDEO_STABILIZATION):

> iOS 6 introduced API support for video stabilization on the iPhone 4s. The back-facing camera on the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus supports a more aggressive, dramatic, and fluid algorithm called “cinematic video stabilization”. This stabilization method reduces the camera’s field of view compared to standard video stabilization, introduces much more latency in the video capture pipeline compared to standard video stabilization, and consumes significantly more system memory. For these reasons, it is not on by default and must be opted in to use.
>
> When using cinematic video stabilization, it is recommended that you use narrow or identical min and max frame durations to keep the latency consistent and manageable. iPhone 6 and 6 Plus also support the standard (lower latency, less dramatic) video stabilization algorithm used in earlier products. Previously, the AVCaptureConnection allowed you to opt in for video stabilization by calling the AVCaptureConnection setEnablesVideoStabililzationWhenAvailable: method. AV Foundation now supports more than one type of video stabilization, so that method has been deprecated (along with AVCaptureConnection videoStabilizationEnabled:) in favor of a new method, AVCaptureConnection setPreferredVideoStabilizationMode:.
>
> You may set your preferred video stabilization mode to one of 4 constants: AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff, AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeStandard, AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeCinematic, or AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto. You can query the AVCaptureDevice activeFormat property to determine what stabilization modes it supports by calling AVCaptureDeviceFormat isVideoStabilizationModeSupported:. Setting the preferred stabilization mode to a constant other than AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff does not force video stabilization on. Some device formats and AVCaptureOutput's don’t support stabilization. To determine which video stabilization mode is actually in use, you can key-value observe the AVCaptureConnection activeVideoStabilizationMode property. When you set your preferred stabilization mode to AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeAuto, an appropriate stabilization mode will be chosen based on the format and frame rate in use. Currently, only the 1080p30 and 1080p60 video formats support cinematic stabilization. The default value for preferredVideoStabilizationMode is AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeOff. As on earlier products, only the 16:9 video formats support stabilization.